# Trying to find the content of a cell next to the array formula's match

Tags: google-sheets

I tried to find if someone had a similar request but I really can't find anything anymore. Basically, I got the following set up:

I got 2 named Ranges, both with 1 column called "ID":

```
Named Range 1: Rank,     Real Name,      ID
Named Range 2: UserName, Email,     Tag, ID
```

Now in the second Range, I would like to add a column with the rank of the user but only if that ID also appears in range 1.

What I tried to do was a `MATCH` function, but I can only get a string to come out if the IDs match, not the rank which is in a different column (column A of the second range).

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D2:D200,'Top 100 List'!C2:C151,0)),"No","Yes"))
```

I got it to write "Yes" to all the items that are also in the other named sheet but instead of that, I would like to give me the value of the named range in A from that specific cell.

Edit: I made a copy of the sheet because of sensitive information so you can see it In the sheet "Registrations" column H I would like to get the ranks from the other sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PzItmS3j-orH74E2zFlNWbvw39GdDGwuYL_jgzNAi7U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I made a copy of the sheet because of sensitive information: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PzItmS3j-orH74E2zFlNWbvw39GdDGwuYL_jgzNAi7U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D2:D200,'Top 100 List'!C2:C151,0)),"No",
 VLOOKUP(D2:D,{'Top 100 List'!C2:C151,'Top 100 List'!A2:A151},2,0)),))
```

[image: 0]